# MongoDB: aggregating by property names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection within which each document looks a bit like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b9fe6010c969210d442a377"),
    "statuses" : {
        "SEARCHING" : 3
    },
    "regions" : {
        "eu-central-1" : 1,
"us-west-2": 2
    }
}
```

I want to group and transform this into a result set like this:

```
eu-central-1|us-west-2
1|2
```

Is this possible in one step/query?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "regions": { $objectToArray: "$regions" } // convert sub-document into an array of key-value-pairs in order to get hold of the field names
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$regions" // flatten the "regions" array
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$regions.k",
        "count": { $sum: "$regions.v" } //
    }
})
```

Alternatively, if you really want to get a pipe-delimited output here is what you'd do:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $project: {
        "result": {
            $reduce: {
                "input": { $objectToArray: "$regions" },
                "initialValue": { k: "", v: "" }, // start with empty strings for both key and value
                "in": {
                    k: { $concat: [ "$$value.k", "|", "$$this.k" ] }, // concatenate existing value with "|" followed by currently looked at value for both key and value
                    v: { $concat: [ "$$value.v", "|", { $substr: [ "$$this.v", 0, 1000 ] } ] } // substr is needed to convert an integer field into a string
                    //v: { $concat: [ "$$value.v", "|", { $toString: "$$this.v" } ] } // this works from MongoDB v4.0 onwards and looks a bit cleaner
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: { // remove the leading "|"
        "result.k": { $substr: [ "$result.k", 1, -1 ] },
        "result.v": { $substr: [ "$result.v", 1, -1 ] }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer (and especially for going the extra mile; the pipe delimited thing was me trying to make a table!). This doesn't quite seem to work though. I still get individual rows for each entry in the original collection. I want to group by the key names and display an aggregate. I'm happy to share a mongodump of the source if that helps.

Comment: Regarding the pipe thing: LOL, gotcha. It would be helpful if you could post the expected result in JSON format as this is what you are going to get from MongoDB. The first query I posted should give you one result document per distinct field name inside your "regions" array.